# jqplot and primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

So I upgrade to Primefaces 3.0 from 2.2 in order to use the new charts.  However, the ability to format the axes and tooltip is no longer there.  Is there a way that I can get to the jqplot's chart and change these ?  The old 2.2 version has dataTipFunction.  Thanks for any help you can give me.  It seems a lot of people are having the same problem as me.

Comment: Just want to follow up that I can't figure out how to get the jqplot handle from primefaces, so I ended up creating the jqplot myself.  Oh well!!!  Work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

The extender property worked for me. Here is how I did it

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
            function open() {
                this.cfg.axes = {
                    xaxis: {
                        showTicks: false
                    }
                };
</script>
```

My linechart looked like this -

```
<pf:lineChart id="TraceJobChart"
       value="#{tracejobsController.getChartForDialog()}"
       legendPosition=""
       yaxisLabel="Traffic"
       xaxisLabel="Time"
       zoom="true" 
       extender="open"
       showMarkers="true"
       shadow="true"
       seriesColors="ff0000" 
       style="height:200px; width: 100%" />
```

The other options that I could have used for linechart are given in this website.

[Jqplot for Linechart](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/line-charts.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the extender property added to latest snapshot of primefaces (3.4-Snapshot)
I have not tried it myself but I think you can do it using extender property.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up backing out and moving down to version 2.2 because of various problem with 3.0.  If I do move back up to version 3.4, I will try.